# grep comma separated-fields with multiple conditions

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, regular-expression

I have a large text file on a Linux server containing the following, for example:

```
123456789012345,00,0000,0000
1234567890123450,00,0000,000
12345678901b111,0,0000,0000
1234567/89011111,00,0000,00000
```

OUTPUT

```
12345678901b111,0,0000,0000       line# 3
1234567/8011111?,00,0000,00000    line# 4
```

so my target is:

I would like to grep lines which is

```
not 15 or 16 digits only before first comma
not 2 digits only before second comma
not 3 or 4 digits only before third comma
not 3 or 4 digits only after third comma

**the line should cover ANY of the predefined conditions**
```

with printing line number for each line and save to another text.

Comment: your output does not fit 2 requirements `not 2 digits only before second comma` and `not 3 or 4 digits only after third comma` . Update your question

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest welcome :) king long time i didn't see ya, hope you ok. looks like you misunderstood me. i want to grep only if condition applied. so if it's not 2 digits before second comma and not 3 or 4 digits after third comma so i want to grep it as my output show

Comment: again, the condition `not 2 digits only before second comma` does not cover the 2nd line `1234567/8011111?,00,0000,0000` from your output. Make your conditions more clear

Comment: yes but it's cover the first condition which is "not 15 or 16 digits only before first comma"

Comment: Then, you must have been specified in your question that the line should cover **ANY** of the predefined conditions. Just do a proper formulations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`AWK`** solution:

```
awk -F, '$1!~/[0-9]{15,16}/ || $2!~/[0-9]{2}/ || $3!~/[0-9]{3,4}/ || $4!~/[0-9]{3,4}/{ 
             printf "%-35s line# %s\n",$0,NR 
         }' file
```

- `-F,` - treating comma `,` as field separator
- `printf "%-35s line# %s\n"` - aligned/arranged formatted output

---

The output:

```
12345678901b111,0,0000,0000         line# 3
1234567/89011111,00,0000,00000      line# 4
```

Comment: I have edit my question in order to print the output with line number

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, ok, see my update

Comment: AWESOME !! BIG MILLION THANKS FOR YOU THAT YOU SAVED MY TIME

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη, you're welcome, glad to help

Comment: based on the same example, how can i print lines which is 4 digits after last comma